# Set common custom error page for all status code in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, custom-error-pages

I am setting custom page for error in my application from web.config or IIS.

An issue is I have to set it for all status codes as below.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
  <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/CS/ShowError.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/CS/ShowError.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/CS/ShowError.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/CS/ShowError.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="501" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/CS/ShowError.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

I want a solution that will allow setting a custom error page once and will work for all status codes like following.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultPath="/CS/ShowError.aspx" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" existingResponse="Replace">
</httpErrors>
```

Unfortunately, above solution does not work. any idea how to get it done?

Currently, I am getting an error like following. I don't want this error page to be displayed but want to set custom page.

[image]

Comment: How about `<customErrors defaultRedirect="/CS/ShowError.apsx"
              mode="On|Off|RemoteOnly">`

Comment: Yes, Tried... not working

Comment: so what your getting on error?

Comment: Updated question for showing what I have currently.

Comment: can you please share your web.config file

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On"
                      defaultRedirect="~/CS/ShowError.aspx" />
```

Comment: This will give a runtime error.  Try to close the tag properly.

Comment: All tags are closed properly but above solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: he probably meant the closing tag of configuration and system.web in my example. They were here only to give the place where to put the customErrors tag.